Controlling stepper motor without step/dir
I am using the motor driver TMC2130 (see datasheet below) to control a stepper motor. I want to make some changes on the registers to improve the system (reduce current consumption when in stand still for exemple) so I am using the third mode available to us to use the driver, the SPI mode. The thing is that I am seeing everywere that even thought the configuration is done by SPI, I still need to use step/dir to have mouvement. Could it be done by the driver itself with parameters I set over the spi? In the datasheet, page 6 it is written " Please refer to Figure 1.1 for more information about the pinning, which is identical to step/direction driver mode, except that the STEP & DIR pins are not required for operation." I am using a raspberry pi and from what I have read, not the best for pwm. I am then wondering what I should send from the raspberry pi to control my motors if it's not connected to the step/dir pins. Thanks for your input.
What I have tried is to connect the rapsberry pi to the driver via the spi pins with the cs pin connected to the ground, the step/dir are not connected to anything. I have send via spi some change on a few registers but now i'm stuck, i don't know wich way to go to send to the driver via spi --> here is the direction for the rotation, rotate of that angle, the speed , for how long ...
TMC2130 Datasheet

The datasheet is the chip itself. Did you make the circuit or is it a prebuilt module/shield/hat?
If you made the circuit, SPI_Mode pin 10 or 12 (depending on ic package) is not a data input; it's either high or low to enable or disable SPI, respectively.
But if you've got a shield/module microcontrollertutorials seems like a better reference than this hackaday article. Still though, SPI is tied high with "board pin" DIAG0.

Hi, this datasheet is indeed for the chip itself but the board I am usind has no specific name, there is a bridge that can be soldered to disable the SPI_mode . I know  now that you still have to use the step/dir pins to control your motor or you in for a lot of hard work to make your own sinus wave because this chip doesnt have a built in ramp generator.
